# Java KeyEvent not seeing keys pressed

Tags: java, awt

The problem that I am having is that my object is not moving and I can't figure out why that is. I have the KeyEvent and the listener but when I tryed to make it print the key values it would not print anything or that it was not seeing anything. I have been using the tutorial lets build a game on youtube to make this so the code should work but again as i stated nothing is happening.

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1550691097823471818L;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private Handler handler;
private Random r;
public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH/12*9;

public Game(){
    handler = new Handler();
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "The Runner", this);
    r = new Random();

    handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH/2 - 32,HEIGHT/2 -32, ID.player));
}
public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}
public synchronized void stop(){
    try{
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void run(){
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double ammountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / ammountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1){
            ticks();
            delta --;
        }
        if(running)
            render();
        frames ++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            //System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void ticks(){
    handler.tick();
}

private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){ 
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    handler.render(g);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Game();

}
}
```

and KeyInput:

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {
private Handler handler; 
public KeyInput(Handler handler){
    this.handler = handler;
}
public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0;(i< handler.object.size()); i ++){

        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.player){

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){ 
                tempObject.setvelY(-5);
            }

        }
    }

}

public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

}
}
package com.tutorial.main;
```

and Handler:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i ++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i ++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);

        }
    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);

    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.remove(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this `Handler`? as stated in TheOnlyMrCat's answer use override, but make sure to start method names with lower case letters, otherwise it will fail

Comment: You never call `start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to declare the methods like this:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0;(i< handler.object.size()); i ++){

        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.player){

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){ 
                tempObject.setvelY(-5);
            }

        }
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

}
```

1. The `@Override` annotations throw an error when the superclass doesn't have the specified method
2. By convention, all Java methods begin with a lowercase letter, unlike types which begin with an uppercase

Comment: That did not fix my problem thank you for the help tough.

Comment: @Cory but using `@Override` should indicate the error - *assuming*  that the `Handler` is correct. Use a debugger or add `System.out.println("pressed " + e);` at the beginning of each listener method to confirm that it is at least being called... I'm also not very sure if youtube and videos are the best alternatives to learn programming...

Comment: @Cory well here is the plain text from the KeyAdapter class:

`public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}, public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}`